# RegEx : Match a string enclosed in single quotes but don't match those inside double quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I wanted to write a regex to match the strings enclosed in single quotes but should not match a string with single quote that is enclosed in a double quote.

**Example 1:**

```
a = 'This is a single-quoted string';
```

the whole value of **a** should match because it is enclosed with single quotes.

EDIT: Exact match should be: 
**'This is a single-quoted string'**

**Example 2:**

```
x = "This is a 'String' with single quote";
```

**x** should not return any match because the single quotes are found inside double quotes.

I have tried **/'.*'/g** but it also matches the single quoted string inside a double quoted string.

**Thanks for the help!**

EDIT:

To make it clearer

Given the below strings:

```
The "quick 'brown' fox" jumps
over 'the lazy dog' near
"the 'riverbank'".
```

The match should only be:

```
'the lazy dog'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that won't have to deal with escaped quotes (which would be possible but make the regex complicated), and that all quotes are correctly balanced (nothing like `It's... "Monty Python's Flying Circus"!`), then you could look for single-quoted strings that are followed by an even number of double quotes:

```
/'[^'"]*'(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/g
```

See it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/iW6qX3).

**Explanation:**

```
'        # Match a '
[^'"]*   # Match any number of characters except ' or "
'        # Match a '
(?=      # Assert that the following regex could match here:
 (?:     # Start of non-capturing group:
  [^"]*" # Any number of non-double quotes, then a quote.
  [^"]*" # The same thing again, ensuring an even number of quotes.
 )*      # Match this group any number of times, including zero.
 [^"]*   # Then match any number of characters except "
 $       # until the end of the string.
)        # (End of lookahead assertion)
```

Comment: Thanks dude, i have put x on top and a at the second line.  the match returned is wrong.  http://regex101.com/r/tF5mB8

Comment: @s4m0k: Good catch, I edited the regex - better now?

Comment: Oh man you're a genius! Perfect! Thank you so much! and +1 for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
^[^"]*?('[^"]+?')[^"]*$
```

#### [Live Demo](http://rubular.com/r/aG8FcwP2cK)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  But this regex selects everything outside the single quote.  It should only match the exact string in single-quotes.

Comment: Hmmm, but you said this: `the whole value of a should match because it is enclosed with single quotes.`

Comment: Thats right the value of a is 'This is a single-quoted string'.  sorry for the confusion, I edited the output.

Comment: I have tried this in the Live Demo, **y = 'Should match'; some string here should not match.**  But it matches from y until the dot (.).  It should only match 'Should match'

Comment: Appreciate the help.  That's close to what i wanted.  But the output that I really want is this.  http://regex101.com/r/sP6cM1  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not strictly bounded by the regex, you could use the function "indexOf" to find out if it's a substring of the double quoted match:

```
var a = "'This is a single-quoted string'";
var x = "\"This is a 'String' with single quote\"";

singlequoteonly(x);

function singlequoteonly(line){
    var single, double = "";
    if ( line.match(/\'(.+)\'/) != null ){
        single = line.match(/\'(.+)\'/)[1];
    }
    if( line.match(/\"(.+)\"/) != null ){
        double = line.match(/\"(.+)\"/)[1];
    }

    if( double.indexOf(single) == -1 ){
        alert(single + " is safe");
    }else{
        alert("Warning: Match [ " + single + " ] is in Line: [ " + double + " ]");
    }
}
```

See the JSFiddle below:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A9Yhs/1/)